# Get outside text and inside text for brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query and returning values like below

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(100) =  'lablablablalbaalala (blibliblobloblo) blalblalala (blululublululu)'

SELECT
    LEFT(value, CHARINDEX(')', value)-1)
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT(@foo, '(')
WHERE
    value LIKE '%)%'
```

| Column |
| --- |
| blibliblobloblo |
| blululublululu |

But I would like to get outside text also in to another column  in SQL server.

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| lablablablalbaalala | blibliblobloblo |
| blalblalala | blululublululu |

Please help.

Comment: So you want to split the data on to two rows? What happens if the last part of your string is not in brackets? What happens if the first part of your string _is in brackets? What if there are no brackets at all?

Comment: would like to get data only if string on the right side ( 1st row), brackets value in 2nd row...@gvee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
 SELECT
        LEFT(value, CHARINDEX('(', value)-1) as before, 
        Right(value,LEN(value)- CHARINDEX('(', value)) as after
    FROM
        STRING_SPLIT(@foo, ')')
    WHERE
        value LIKE '%(%'
```

Comment: can we achieve this without STRING_SPLIT also ?@saeed

Comment: @ANR Yes you can but the result should be same as ``String_Split``. because the string should split in multiple rows

Comment: From [`String_Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The output rows might be in any order. The order is _not_ guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad : String_Split is not supporting in my SQL server and could you please provide alternate?

Comment: @ANR [Jeff Moden's string splitter](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function). It does guarantee the order of the results.